# GDPR - Analytics : User consent before any tracking?

Tags: cookies, analytics

I have a very specific question about G. Analytics and the GDPR law.
I've read many topics about this, but answers are sometimes contradictory. I would love to have an answer from a G.A. expert or a lawyer.

The GDPR law indicates that we must obtain the user consent before data treatment ; so for me, it would suggest that we must deactivate G.A. tracking as long as user doesn't optin to that treatment.
If I do so : I refresh the page when user has optin, so the data collection can begin ; Problem doing that : we loose the referrer param (since we do a JS refresh, this param is lost : referrer will be the current page)

Others questions :

- If I activated IP anonymisation on G.A. : Must I obtain the user consent or can I send the datas by default (and offer the possibility to user for opt-out) ? (many websites seems to have this process, but it seems contradictory with the user-consent obligation...) but this [topic](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/29160/handling-a-gdpr-subject-access-request-when-using-google-analytics) suggest to proceed like this.
- Regarding cookie law : Is it allowed to store in cookies the user client-id (that G.A. uses) without the user consent ? If not, how to workaround this limitation, and use G.A. without allowing it to set cookies ?
- Is there a way to store user activity without sending it to G.A, and when user opt-in -> send all that datas ?

Many thanks in advance !

Comment: Did you ever uncover appropriate solution for passing referrer information?

Comment: I voted to close this question cause it lacks focus, seeks legal advice and is not a programming question. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer*: Not a lawyer

There are some cookies that can be set without consent (e.g. for security purposes, or perhaps even a preference for cookies). These are generally meant for essential purposes only and not for analytics, functional, or performance purposes.

However, if referrals are a critical part of how your website functions (say for example process discounts if it came from a certain link), it might be considered essential. The lines are bit blurry on what can be considered 'essential', and indeed 'legitimate interest' for non-essential functions.

If you visit websites and look in dev tools, cookies are there immediately even for websites that are showing a cookie consent banner.

**-- As for non-cookie technical ways --**

I do have a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69746442/does-non-cookie-based-tracking-need-gdpr-consent-to-end-user) that is open to answers on whether non-cookie based tracking technologies fall into the scope of consent - you could potentially send information to the server-side.

You might also use a front-end framework to construct a Single Page Application (although you might not have the option in a company), so that the page is not actually reloaded on a consent click. The consent form can simply trigger a script to run / change a state variable so that information that were stored in JS as variables can now be written into cookies.

Comment: The question is asking for legal advice and, therefore, is off topic and you should vote to close this instead. On top of that, it's not a programming question. And neither is your question you linked to. You should delete that one (and it's the reason no one should answer it.).